# Page not found for the template returned by TemplateResponse in Django

Tags: django, wagtail

I have an app which is called `sitepages` which have three models I wanna pass their objects to a html page called `listing.html` which is inside `templates/sitepages`
the sitepages urls.py contains:

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from django.urls import include
from django.urls import path
from sitepages import views

app_name = "sitepages"

urlpatterns = [
    path("news-events-listing/", views.view, name='listing'),
]
```

the sitepages/views.py:

```
from .models import Listing, Details1, Details2
from django.template.response import TemplateResponse

def view(request):
    return TemplateResponse(request, 'sitepages/listing.html', {
            'first_pages': Details1.objects.all(),
            'seconde_pages': Details1.objects.all(),
            'listing_page': Listing.objects.first(),
        })
```

in the root urls.py I added:

```
path("", include("sitepages.urls", namespace='sitepages'))
```

when I put in any template the following:

```
<a href="{% url 'sitepages:listing' %}">Listing</a>
```

it redirects me to the url `/news-events-listing` but no page is found and it gives me 404 error...what am I doing wrong? why the template is not returned? I should mention that I'm using wagtail for the whole site (I don't know if it's related)

Comment: Try changing the URL of the anchor tag to just `listing` like this: ```<a href="{% url 'listing' %}">Listing</a>```. Also please include the whole error so that we can see the entire log.

Comment: @Shayan I can't call it using `listing` only cause I have a namespace, also if I removed the namespace I would get `NoReverseMatch` error, for my case I didn't put the entire log cause there's no log, just the standard Django 404 page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your root urls.py, make sure your new line

```
path("", include("sitepages.urls", namespace='sitepages'))
```

appears *before* the `path("", include(wagtail_urls))` line. The `wagtail_urls` pattern matches any URL path and passes it to Wagtail to be handled as a Wagtail page, so any patterns after it will never be reached.

Comment: can you please check the new problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67087487/using-the-urlconf-defined-django-tried-these-url-patterns-with-i18n?noredirect=1#comment118583455_67087487